# Running Total as SUM () OVER () in SQL when values are missing

Tags: sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to calculate Running Total and it works correct but only when values I'm conditioning on are available. When some are unavailable, calculation is going wrong, some NULLs happen and at the end Running Total is incorrect, here's the example of such situation:

[image: this is when there was no values for some month_number]

and I would like to be set like on the screen shot below (with missing months added), which should give correct Running Total (named backlog here) at the end:

[image: expected result]

Is there any way to define full_year and month_number columns to be visible with '0' value set when there was no value?

My current query is as below:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp4') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp4
end

SELECT * into #Temp4
   from (
SELECT
 datepart(yy, t3.[datestamp]) AS full_year 
,datepart(mm, t3.[datestamp]) AS month_number
,count(*) as number_of_activities
,t2.affected_item
FROM [sm70prod].[dbo].[ACTSVCMGTM1] AS t3 
JOIN [sm70prod].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1] AS t2 ON t3.number = t2.incident_id
WHERE
t2.affected_item like 'service'
AND (t3.[type] LIKE 'Open')
GROUP BY t2.affected_item, datepart(yy, t3.[datestamp]), datepart(mm, t3.[datestamp])
)
as databases (full_year, month_number, number_of_activities, affected_item)

;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp5') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp5
end

SELECT * into #Temp5
   from (
SELECT
 datepart(yy, t3.[datestamp]) AS full_year 
,datepart(mm, t3.[datestamp]) AS month_number
,count(*) as number_of_activities
,t2.affected_item
FROM [sm70prod].[dbo].[ACTSVCMGTM1] AS t3 
JOIN [sm70prod].[dbo].[INCIDENTSM1] AS t2 ON t3.number = t2.incident_id
WHERE
t2.affected_item like 'service'
AND (t3.[type] LIKE 'Closed')
GROUP BY t2.affected_item, datepart(yy, t3.[datestamp]), datepart(mm, t3.[datestamp])
)
as databases (full_year, month_number, number_of_activities, affected_item)

select * from (select o.full_year 
,o.month_number
,o.number_of_activities as [open]
,c.number_of_activities as [close]
,sum(o.number_of_activities - c.number_of_activities) over (ORDER BY c.full_year, c.month_number) as [backlog]
from #Temp4 o full join #Temp5 c on o.full_year = c.full_year and o.month_number = c.month_number) as sub
order by full_year, month_number
```

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190349%28v=sql.110%29.aspx
Try using the coalesce function:

```
COALESCE(someattribute, 0);
```

if the attribute is NULL the value zero will be used instead.

Also note:

When comparing varchars without a regex
 you should use the    =   operator and not the LIKE operator.

Comment: I could use COALESCE for 'open' or 'close' columns but first I need to some how add rows with missing months, where I can't use COALESCE. With finding a way how to present missing months, there should be no NULLs in 'open' and 'close' columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for that. For missing months I can use the code as below:

```
    If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp6') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp6
End

create table #Temp6

(
full_year int
,month_number int
)
; WITH cteStartDate AS
 (SELECT StartDate = '2007-01-01'),
 cteSequence(SeqNo) 
     AS (SELECT 0 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT SeqNo + 1 
         FROM   cteSequence 
         WHERE  SeqNo < DATEDIFF(MM,(SELECT StartDate FROM cteStartDate),getdate())) 

INSERT INTO #Temp6
SELECT datepart(yy, DATEADD(MM,SeqNo,(SELECT StartDate FROM cteStartDate))) AS full_year 
,datepart(mm, DATEADD(MM,SeqNo,(SELECT StartDate FROM cteStartDate))) AS month_number
FROM   cteSequence
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Then I can use `full join` with `#Temp4`, add `ISNULL(o.number_of_activities, 0)`, the same for `#Temp5` and it will work.